# Difference between ActiveRecord::Base.connection and find_by_sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I need to perform some custom queries on my rails application and was wondering which approach is better:

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Or

```
Model.find_by_sql(query)
```

Been reading the documentation but didn't really get how they perform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`execute` is a low level method. It returns whatever the database driver returns, for example an instance of `Mysql2::Result`. You can execute any sort of query with this

`find_by_sql` returns an array of ActiveRecord objects of the appropriate class, constructed from the results (so it wouldn't make sense to pass a query that doesn't produce a suitable result set).

A halfway house are methods on connection such as `select_all`, `select_values` etc. These don't create active record objects, but do transform the raw driver results into arrays, hashes, strings etc.